# Angular http get returns string in extra quotes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, string, angularjs

My project is a mixture of AngularJS and ASP.Net MVC.

I am using `$http.get` to call my api controller, which returns a string. But in the `.success` function, the data is getting returned like so `"/"my string/""`  (with the extra quotes around it).

Why are those there, and how can I get rid of them?

I need them gone because I am setting the title attribute of an element to the string that is returned, and this makes the tooltip have quotes around it (ugly).

Comment: try `JSON.parse(variable)`

Comment: You are a genius and I am a dummy :P Can't believe I didn't think of that! If you want to make that an answer, I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

parse the string value using `JSON.parse(variable)`